# gitlab: how to trigger a pipline in another project

Tags: gitlab

I have a `gitlab` repo `MAIN`, where I run a pipline.

I have another `gitlab` repo `SUB`. where I run another pipeline

Now I want to trigger the pipline in `MAIN` repo from the `SUB`

i.e whenever i commit any change in `SUB` it should trigger the pipeline in `MAIN`

How do I do that in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file of the `SUB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trigger-main:
  trigger: group/MAIN
```

ref:
[Multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#trigger-job-fails-and-does-not-create-multi-project-pipeline)

Comment: The link is broken, valid URL is: [Downstream pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html?tab=Multi-project+pipeline)

Comment: @ChristianSchulzendorff  I'm fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Pipeline Triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/):

- in `MAIN`, you [add a new trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#adding-a-new-trigger)
- in `SUB`, you [trigger the pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline) in `MAIN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html), for example :

```sh
curl --request POST \
     --form token=TOKEN \
     --form ref=main \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline"
```

You need an [Authentication token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#authentication-tokens)